# Restructure if else conditions if possible

Tags: java, if-statement

I need some help with re-structuring the if-else conditions I have in my program. It is a trivial problem but I've been working long hours and can't seem to find a good solution.

These are the conditions if I have to state:

```
 This method should be executed for type 'A' objects iff `newValue` is 0, 
 otherwise it should be run only for type 'B' objects.
```

I'd like to avoid the nested ifs in this code.

```
 public static void someMethod(final Object object) {

    if (MyObjects.getType(object) == ObjectType.A) {
        if (newValue != 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("newValue for A can only be 0");
        }
    } else if (MyObjects.getType(object) != ObjectType.B) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid object type received.");
    }

    // More code here
 }
```

Comment: I don't really see the issue.

Comment: What's the problem? Does this not work as expected?

Comment: @GregHewgill the problem is writing that sort of code to begin with. OP, please do not do type sniffing like that - it's a big anti pattern, learn about writing polymorphic code instead. If the method should be executed for objects of type `A` under a condition otherwise type `b` have both of them implement an interface and put the execution logic there. That way you avoid this mess altogether.

Comment: Well, yes, that would almost certainly be a better solution given the code in the question. However, that seems to go beyond the scope of what this question is asking, since the same boolean logic question could apply equally well to something without objects.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I agree with you and the trade-off was between code - duplication with polymorphic code vs type-sniffing. I changed my approach and wrote polymorphic code on reading your vote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to remove the inner if, then add `newValue != 0` to the first condition..

```
public static void someMethod(final Object object) {

   if (MyObjects.getType(object) == ObjectType.A && newValue != 0) {
           throw new IllegalStateException("newValue for A can only be 0");
   } else if (MyObjects.getType(object) != ObjectType.B) {
       throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid object type received.");
   }

   // More code here
}
```

Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: No, no, no!!  If `getType` is `A`, and `newValue` is 0, then it will fail the second `if` and throw an exception, which is not what you want.  This has a very different effect than the original code, which _never_ gets to the second `if` if `getType` is `A`.

Comment: Speaking pseudo-code, you need: `if !(type == B or (type == A and value !=0)` then throw an Exception. But this is not possible if you need to throw two different exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((MyObjects.getType(object) == ObjectType.A) && (newValue != 0)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("newValue for A can only be 0");
} else if (MyObjects.getType(object) != ObjectType.B) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid object type received.");
}
```

Comment: No, no, no!! If `getType` is `A`, and `newValue` is 0, then it will fail the second `if` and throw an exception, which is not what you want. This has a very different effect than the original code, which _never_ gets to the second `if` if `getType` is `A`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void someMethod(final Object object) {

    if ((object instanceof A && newValue==0)) || object instanceof B) {
        //then execute.
    }

 }
```

Comment: No, no, no!!  The OP never said `A` and `B` were class names, and never told us what `getType` actually does.  However, the general approach is correct if you get rid of the incorrect `instanceof`'s, but you'll need to do more work to get the exception message right.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void someMethod(final Object object) {

    if ((MyObjects.getType(object) == ObjectType.A && newValue != 0) || (MyObjects.getType(object) != ObjectType.B)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("newValue for A can only be 0 OR Invalid object type received.");
        }
    // More code here
 }
```